# Error creating new environment in miniconda3 on ubuntu 16

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, miniconda, newenvironment

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/elnstaff/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 297, in recv_into
        return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/elnstaff/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1822, in recv_into
        self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
      File "/home/elnstaff/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1622, in _raise_ssl_error
        raise WantReadError()
    OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: You are not showing how you're trying to create the new environment, your question is just a copy-paste of your error. (and not the complete error it seems) If you don't explain what's going on, it's impossible to help you. Please see [ask]

Comment: yeh , you are right . i will update the querry